# SQL Mostrar resultado de consulta con valores existentes y nulls en caso de no existir

Tags: sql

Buena noche para solicitar de su apoyo en adecuar una consulta en sql en la cual estoy utilizando la sentencia "union" para unir 2 consultas en sql pero necesito que el resultado muestre los 2 registros aunque en uno no exista el valor buscado.

el query que estoy utilizando:

```
SELECT pts_idparte, pts_desparte , pts_pcolista,  ALM_EXISTEN 
from par_almacen inner join par_partes  on  ALM_IDPARTE=PTS_IDPARTE and 
ALM_IDPARTE = '4261102M50' and ALM_IDALMA ='GEN' 
union 
SELECT pts_idparte, pts_desparte , pts_pcolista,  ALM_EXISTEN 
from par_almacen inner join par_partes  on  ALM_IDPARTE=PTS_IDPARTE and 
ALM_IDPARTE = '4261102X' and ALM_IDALMA ='GEN'
```

El primer select muestra un registro donde si existe el ALM_IDPARTE
en el segudo select no existe sin embargo el resultado de la consulta solo muestra el primer registro y se require que muestre el segundo como NULL si no existe.

resultado actual:

```
pts_idparte     pts_desparte    pts_pcolista    ALM_EXISTEN
4261102M50      WHEEL, DISC     6608.05000      0.0000000
```

resultado esperado:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
pts_idparte     pts_desparte    pts_pcolista    ALM_EXISTEN
4261102M50      WHEEL, DISC     6608.05000      0.0000000
------------------------------------------------------------------
pts_idparte    pts_desparte    pts_pcolista     ALM_EXISTEN
NULL           NULL             NULL             NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: ¿qué gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: Microsoft Sql 2008R2